# Level shifting not working properly - strange offset

Tags: sensor, ground, level-shifting

12 sensor connected to an ESP32. Since the ESP32 works with 3.3 V and the sensor output voltage is 5 Vdc. I added a level shifter, in particular this [level shifter mosfet](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/bi-directional-logic-level-converter-hookup-guide/all).

Basically I have:

1. 12 Vdc to power the sensor and the ESP32;
2. A 12 Vdc to 3.3 V regulator and a 12 Vdc to 5 Vdc regulator;
3. Common GND between ESP32 and sensor and power supplies;
4. The sensor goes on HV1 and PIN of ESP32 for SDI goes to LV1 of the MOSFET level shifter;
5. LV connected to 3.3 V, HV connected to 5V dc

[image: List item]

If I test with this setup I have some sort of offset from 0 V on the 3.3 V side, so the ESP does not detect the response.

[image]

If I use a simple voltage divider everything works properly.

In this case the voltage generator is the sensor output and the signal indicated with 3.205 is where I connected the input pin of the ESP32, GND in common.

[image]

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Check that your HV1 output is fully going to 0 volts when it should.

Comment: Are you actually using the SparkFun level shifter PCB (from SparkFun), or just their schematic? What is the magnitude of the offset? If your sensor does clock stretching, does the clock level shifter channel have the same issue? Can you add the 5V side of the level shifter to the scope trace? Does it happen if you use a different channel of the level shifter?

Comment: @W5VO yes, sparkfun, no, I'm using only this signal, since I have only this output from the sensor, I'll try to check the HV side as suggested

Comment: Looks like a diode drop.  Is the FET backwards?

Comment: Unless you haven't switched LV and HV as Aaron stated, are you sure that the high side "HV1" is pulled to GND and not to the 0.5V-ish offset you see ?

Answer (score 2):

If you have the gate connected to LV1 (or 0V) rather than LV you'll get that waveform.

[image]

That's because there is insufficient Vgs to turn the MOSFET on and only the body diode conducts.

If the MOSFET is  not a BSS138 or equivalent you could also get similar behavior because Vgs(th) is too high.

Comment: Nope, Gates are connected to 3V3(LV) or 5Vdc(HV)